# “vagrant” will damage your computer. | macOS v12 (Monterey) #13132

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, homebrew, homestead

Today morning suddenly I started getting this popup whenever I ran Vagrant up in my Mac.

[image]

[VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) version 7.0.4 r154605 (Qt5.15.2). 
[macOS v12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) (Monterey), MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

| Ubuntu LTS | Settler Version | Homestead Version | Branch | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.04 | 11.x | 12.x | `main` | Development/Unstable |
| 20.04 | 11.x | 12.x | `release` | Stable |

What's wrong here?

Comment: This usually happens when the software does not come from the App store or some authorization was revoked. I don't know exactly why it happens, but if you're sure you can 'trust' the software you could bypass the mallware protection by right-clicking the software causing the alert. `Get Info` -> `General (expand it)` -> and check `Override Malware Protection`. [Guide](https://iboysoft.com/news/remove-will-damage-your-computer-error-mac.html)

Comment: You can [download the macos bianry from hashicrop site](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/downloads?product_intent=vagrant) and install it. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I also had the same issue after upgrading to [macOS v13.3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura)  (Ventura. 22E261).

Try the following:

1. `brew reinstall --cask vagrant`
2. `vagrant plugin update`

Then the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 39):

The previous fixes look correct. The error itself is due to the signing key being revoked on April 24th, 2023.

Hashicorp did this due to the [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/about/) [data breach](https://circleci.com/blog/jan-4-2023-incident-report/). Details are available at *[Security Alert: HashiCorp Response to CircleCI](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/13177506317203-Security-Alert-HashiCorp-Response-to-CircleCI)*.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error message on [macOS v11.7.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur. 20G1231).

After downloading and reinstalling the AMD64 installer [from Vagrant](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/downloads?product_intent=vagrant) and running

```
vagrant plugin update
vagrant plugin repair
```

in the terminal, everything worked as before.

Comment: Worked here for Monterey 12.6.3 as well. One difference - the warning screen from op's screenshot said "ruby" would damage my computer, instead of vagrant. Obviously vagrant uses ruby, so an update from the AMD64 installer fixed it.

Comment: One other note - if your version of Vagrant isn't too far behind the current version, ```vagrant plugin update``` and ```vagrant plugin repair``` isn't necessary, at least it wasn't for me from v2.3.1 -> v2.3.4

Answer (score 4):

Running

```
brew install hashicorp/tap/hashicorp-vagrant
```

in your CLI will update to latest vagrant and fixes the issue.

Comment: Only this one worked for me, simply installing vagrant was throwing: `Error: The following directories are not writable by your user: /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 4):

For those who are getting a [SHA-256 mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09yOE.png), you can try to run `brew untap vagrant` and `brew tap vagrant` and retry the upper commands:

```
brew reinstall --cask vagrant

vagrant plugin update
```

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled Vagrant, and then it all works again...

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue without upgrading or update macos or anything. Try it;

```
brew install hashicorp/tap/hashicorp-vagrant
```

Solved my problem

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers